# C++ from Linux to Windows

Tags: visual-c++

Im currently rebuilding my project from Linux to Windows and I have little problem with rebuilding functions, Im more experienced on Linux and I dont know how to rebuild functions you see comment on

Only problem is

```
 mprotect(page, mprot_len, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC)
```

This is my code, I dont know replacement for it

```
class BytePatch
{
    void *addr{ 0 };
    size_t size;
    std::vector<unsigned char> patch_bytes;
    std::vector<unsigned char> original;
    bool patched{ false };

public:
    ~BytePatch()
    {
        Shutdown();
    }
    BytePatch(std::function<uintptr_t(const char *)> SigScanFunc, const char *pattern, size_t offset, std::vector<unsigned char> patch) : patch_bytes{ patch }
    {
        addr = (void *) SigScanFunc(pattern);
        if (!addr)
        {
            logging::Info("Signature not found");
            throw std::runtime_error("Signature not found");
        }
        addr = static_cast<void *>(static_cast<char *>(addr) + offset);
        size = patch.size();
        original.resize(size);
        memcpy(&original[0], addr, size);
    }
    BytePatch(uintptr_t addr, std::vector<unsigned char> patch) : addr{ reinterpret_cast<void *>(addr) }, patch_bytes{ patch }
    {
        size = patch.size();
        original.resize(size);
        memcpy(&original[0], reinterpret_cast<void *>(addr), size);
    }
    BytePatch(void *addr, std::vector<unsigned char> patch) : addr{ addr }, patch_bytes{ patch }
    {
        size = patch.size();
        original.resize(size);
        memcpy(&original[0], addr, size);
    }

    void Patch()
    {
        if (!patched)
        {
            void *page          = (void *) ((uint64_t) addr & ~0xFFF);
            void *end_page      = (void *) (((uint64_t)(addr) + size) & ~0xFFF);
            uintptr_t mprot_len = (uint64_t) end_page - (uint64_t) page + 0xFFF;

            mprotect(page, mprot_len, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC); // this one 
            memcpy(addr, &patch_bytes[0], size);
            mprotect(page, mprot_len, PROT_EXEC); // this one 
            patched = true;
        }
    }
    void Shutdown()
    {
        if (patched)
        {
            void *page          = (void *) ((uint64_t) addr & ~0xFFF);
            void *end_page      = (void *) (((uint64_t)(addr) + size) & ~0xFFF);
            uintptr_t mprot_len = (uint64_t) end_page - (uint64_t) page + 0xFFF;

            mprotect(page, mprot_len, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC); // this one
            memcpy(addr, &original[0], size);
            mprotect(page, mprot_len, PROT_EXEC); // this one
            patched = false;
        }
    }
};
```

Thanks in advance people

Comment: `mprotect` is more or less equal to Win32's `VirtualProtect`.

Comment: VirtualProtect requires oldProtection, is there any way to do it without it?

Comment: It's not optional, but the function will provide the value, you just have to provide a place to put it.  "A pointer to a variable that receives the previous access protection value of the first page in the specified region of pages. If this parameter is NULL or does not point to a valid variable, the function fails."  This would allow you to put back the old protection after `memcpy` instead of always execute-only.